# whats wrong with my c++ list<string>

Tags: c++

bee.cpp

```
            list<string> urls;

              urls.push_back ("one");
              urls.push_back ("two");
              urls.push_back ("Three");
              urls.sort();

                  TP(urls);
```

TP.h

```
namespace std {

        class TP {
        public:
            TP(list<string> u);
            virtual ~ThreadPool();
        };

    }
```

TP.c++

```
    TP::TP(list<string> u) {
        list<string>::iterator it;
        for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
            cout << " " << *it;
    }

    TP::~TP() {
        // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    }
```

it works in same function under one file if i use an class it shows me an error

```
../src/Bee.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/Bee.cpp:31: error: conflicting declaration ‘std::TP u’
../src/Bee.cpp:24: error: ‘u’ has a previous declaration as ‘std::list<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > u’
}
#endif /* TP_H_ */

TP.h
```

Comment: You're not allowed to add stuff to the `std` namespace. I don't know if that has anything to do with your problem (because I can't read your code), but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: I don't see any possible redeclaration of `u` in your code. Can you please mark the lines in the code that correspond to the lines in the error?

Comment: You shouldn't pass `std::list` (or any other containers) to functions by value, because it causes copying of all the data. Using constant references would be in order

Comment: Not enough information for meaningful answer. Hmm, you may have missed showing us the lines of code that are responsible for the error. Have you named any other variable 'u'? In the sample of bee.cpp you've given us, there is no declaration of 'u' which is what the error seems to be moaning about.

Comment: Also you are getting `u` as a parameter to the constructor but outputing the contents of `mylist`.

Comment: And you declared a destructor in TP for a class called ThreadPool. Please, if you anonymize code for posting, do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Fred Larson already speculated that your code was wrong because you've been illegally adding stuff to the `std::` namespace. That's true. However, looking at the error about ‘std::TP u’, it's clear that you aren't showing the relevant code at all. You have two declarations of `u` in bee.cpp, and your code excerpt shows neither.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end();
```

should be

```
u.begin(); it!=u.end();
```